# Are questions about convention or style advice on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it acceptable on Stack Overflow to ask for advice on style or the convention on certain styles? For example asking if a Java class is an unnecessary wrapper class.

Comment: An "unnecessary wrapper class" class doesn't sound like a convention or style question to me. Styles/conventions usually deal with things like naming and whitespace norms; they don't provide guidance on how you organize the logic.

Answer (score 22):

No - coding style and conventions are mostly opinion based (there are couple cases where some languages actually require particular coding style, but those are rare and already answered).

Note: whether particular class/code required or not is not "convention or style" advice (unlike whether you should do that or not).

Comment: You can ask about that on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ right?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is probably better suited then programmers.

Comment: @Polygnome I would not state that without caveats. [Code Review has on-topic guidelines that exclude many convention and style questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Questions about working code with a clear purpose are generally on-topic, but **hypothetical or non-working code is off-topic**. Questions are also expected to allow **open-ended feedback**, so questions that only ask about style are frowned upon.

Answer (score 7):

No, that isn't really on topic at Stack Overflow.

Most programming languages have coding conventions described as well, so some googling should solve this for you.

I googled the term *java coding conventions* and got this credited result

> This document serves as the complete definition of Google's coding standards for source code in the Java™ Programming Language. https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html

Comment: The Oracle one is however more "official": http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not. It's opinion based and therefore off-topic.

It *could* be a fit for the [CodeReview Stack Exchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but that depends on the concrete question.